# How can i get a price of application in appstore?

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

I want to get prices of several applications to show them in my app.

Can I do it without parsing AppStore application page?

Does Store kit works only for in-app features?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use this reques https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=284910350

There is price field.

Comment: The documentation is found here:  http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I know is using the [iTunes search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html). 
You can get apps prices and more info in a JSON format.

Comment: The documentation is found here:  http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

Comment: Oops - didn't see you had linked directly to the documentation.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you build your own feed which tell you app the prices you are out of luck.

`StoreKit` is for in-app purchase only.